# 0 - The parameter "roksprocket.providers.path" must be defined

Tags: joomla

i have website developed with cms joomla , it work fine since 2014 but no i have the probleme with message error : 0 - The parameter "roksprocket.providers.path" must be defined.
url website : http://aldimexgroup.com/.
thank you for your help .

Comment: Hi.
Is the issue resolved? I just visited the URL you had provided and I can't seem to find that message?

Comment: Joomla questions are welcome at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.